# Four Rings & Seven Digits

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[image]

Replace a to f with the numbers 1 to 2 & 4 to 7, so that the sum inside each ring is the same. There is only one solution!

Comment: If there is more than one solution, your question will be flagged as too broad!

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Pick one of the solutions and think of an additional rule or pattern that they must follow. That would help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Or possibly ask for a generic solution which can be applied to find all possible solutions.

Comment: There were four equations to start with, and seven variables.  You need to have at least one equation per variable in order to have a unique solution.  The current version is 4 & 6, so there's still potentially multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm sweating here. I've put a 3 in the last ring to make the answer unique. Sorry for the multiple edits and all the confusion.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is now a unique solution. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> a=6; b=4; c=5; d=1; e=2; f=7

And

> The sum is 10 in each circle

Answer (score 5):

Blue circle equals purple, so

```
d+e+f=3+f
d+e=3 (they must equal 1 and 2)
```

and

```
d+e+f=b+c+d
e+f=b+c
```

- e has a maximum value of 2
- Only 4-7 remain, so b+c has a minimum value of 9 (4+5)
- This constrains f to be 7 and e to be 2, leaving d to be 1.
- The total per circle is then 10 and 6 is the only value left for a, so b is 4 and c is 5.

Giving us:

> a=6, b=4, c=5, d=1, e=2, f=7

Answer (score 3):

The unique answer is:

> A, B,C, D,E, F--SUM
>
> (6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 7) [10]